# SQLError #3115 Mismatch in parameter count

Tags: sqlite, parameters

I am getting this error when I am trying to use the SQL UPDATE with a mobile application I am making in Flex builder. I have tried to search it up and removed parameters but even then I get the same code. Any help would be much appreciated

```
SQLError: 'Error #3115: SQL Error.', details:'Mismatch in parameter count. Found 6 in SQL specified and 5 value(s) set in parameters property.
', operation:'execute', detailID:'1004'
    at flash.data::SQLStatement/internalExecute()
    at flash.data::SQLStatement/execute()
    at model::SQLiteDatabase$/updateMember()[/Users/stokhofdavey/Documents/Adobe Flash Builder 4.6/MenuPlannerApplication/src/model/SQLiteDatabase.as:175]
    at views::MemberDetailsView/onSaveButtonClicked()[/Users/stokhofdavey/Documents/Adobe Flash Builder 4.6/MenuPlannerApplication/src/views/MemberDetailsView.mxml:25]
    at views::MemberDetailsView/___MemberDetailsView_Button3_click()[/Users/stokhofdavey/Documents/Adobe Flash Builder 4.6/MenuPlannerApplication/src/views/MemberDetailsView.mxml:45]
```

Here is the MXML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        xmlns:ns1="*"
        title="Member Details">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import model.Dish;
            import model.Member;
            import model.SQLiteDatabase;



            protected function onHomeButtonClicked(event:MouseEvent):void {
                navigator.popView();
            }

            protected function onSaveButtonClicked():void {
                var editNote:Member = new Member();
                editNote.FirstName = efirstname.text;
                editNote.FamilyName = efamilyname.text;
                editNote.Sex = esex.text;
                editNote.Age = eage.text;
                editNote.Notes = enotes.text;
                SQLiteDatabase.updateMember(editNote);

                currentState = "Info";
            }


        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="Info"/>
        <s:State name="Favorites"/>
        <s:State name="EInfo"/>
        <s:State name="EFavorites"/>
    </s:states>
    <s:navigationContent>
        <s:Button label="Back" click="navigator.popView();"/>
    </s:navigationContent>
    <s:actionContent>
        <s:Button includeIn="Info" label="Edit" click.Info="this.currentState=&quot;EInfo&quot;"/>
        <s:Button includeIn="EInfo" label="Save" click="onSaveButtonClicked()"/>

    </s:actionContent>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>


    <s:VGroup x="245" y="10" width="100%" height="354" gap="0"  >
        <ns1:TabMemInfoS includeIn="Favorites" width="60" height="40"/>
        <ns1:TabMebInfoL includeIn="Info" width="70" height="40"/>
        <ns1:TabMemFavoritesS includeIn="Info" width="60" height="40"/>
        <ns1:TabMebInfoL includeIn="EInfo" width="70" height="40"/>
        <ns1:TabMemFavoritesS includeIn="EInfo" width="60" height="40"/>
        <ns1:TabMemInfoS includeIn="EFavorites"/>
        <ns1:TabMemFavoritesL includeIn="EFavorites"/>
        <ns1:TabMemFavoritesL includeIn="Favorites" width="70" height="40"/>
    </s:VGroup>
    <s:Label id="FirstName" includeIn="Info" x="87" y="15" width="148" height="29" text="{data.FirstName}" textAlign="center"
             verticalAlign="middle"/>
    <s:Label id="FamilyName" includeIn="Info" x="87" y="46" width="148" height="29" text="{data.FamilyName}" textAlign="center"
             verticalAlign="middle"/>
    <s:Label id="Age" includeIn="Info" x="9" y="97" width="70" height="31" text="{data.Age}" textAlign="center"
             verticalAlign="middle"/>
    <s:Label id="Sex" includeIn="Info" x="87" y="97" width="70" height="31" text="{data.Sex}" textAlign="center"
             verticalAlign="middle"/>
    <s:Label id="notes" includeIn="Info" x="10" y="150" width="225" height="204" text="{data.Notes}"/>

    <s:Group includeIn="EInfo" width="246" height="364">
        <s:TextInput id="efirstname" x="83" y="10" width="150" text="{data.FirstName}" />
        <s:TextInput id="efamilyname" x="83" y="47" width="150" text="{data.FamilyName}"  />
        <s:TextInput id="eage" x="108" y="88" width="90" text="{data.Age}" />
        <s:TextInput id="esex" x="10" y="88" width="90" text="{data.Sex}" />
        <s:TextArea id="enotes" x="9" y="162" width="227" height="192" text="{data.Notes}" />
    </s:Group>

</s:View>
```

and the 2 .as files:
SQLiteDatabase

```
 package model
{
    import flash.data.SQLConnection;
    import flash.data.SQLResult;
    import flash.data.SQLStatement;
    import flash.events.SQLEvent;
    import flash.filesystem.File;
    import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
    import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
    import model.Dish;
    import model.Member;

    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

    public class SQLiteDatabase
    {
        private static var _sqlConnection:SQLConnection;

        public static function get sqlConnection():SQLConnection
        {
            if (_sqlConnection)
                return _sqlConnection;
            openDatabase(File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("test.db"));
            return _sqlConnection;
        }


        public static function getNote(id:int):Dish
        {
            var sql:String = "SELECT id, title, time, message FROM notes WHERE id=?";
            var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
            stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
            stmt.text = sql;
            stmt.parameters[0] = id;
            stmt.execute();
            var result:Array = stmt.getResult().data;
            if (result && result.length == 1)
                return processRow(result[0]);
            else
                return null;
        }

        public static function getMYBlist(id:int):Dish
        {
            var sql:String = "SELECT id, title, time, message FROM notes WHERE id=?";
            var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
            stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
            stmt.text = sql;
            stmt.parameters[0] = id;
            stmt.execute();
            var result:Array = stmt.getResult().data;
            if (result && result.length == 1)
                return processRow(result[0]);
            else
                return null;
        }

        public static function notes():ArrayCollection
        {
            var noteList:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

            var sql:String = "SELECT id, title, time, message FROM notes";
            var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
            stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
            stmt.text = sql;
            stmt.execute();
            var sqlResult:SQLResult = stmt.getResult();
            if (sqlResult) {
                var result:Array = sqlResult.data;
                if (result) {
                    for (var index:Number = 0; index < result.length; index++) {
                        noteList.addItem(processRow(result[index]));
                    }
                }
            }
            return noteList;
        }

        public static function members():ArrayCollection
        {
            var noteList:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

            var sql:String = "SELECT FirstName, FamilyName, Sex, Age, Notes FROM Members";
            var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
            stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
            stmt.text = sql;
            stmt.execute();
            var sqlResult:SQLResult = stmt.getResult();
            if (sqlResult) {
                var result:Array = sqlResult.data;
                if (result) {
                    for (var index:Number = 0; index < result.length; index++) {
                        noteList.addItem(processRow2(result[index]));
                    }
                }
            }
            return noteList;
        }


        public static function addNote(note:Dish):void
        {
            var sql:String = 
                "INSERT INTO notes (title, time, message) " +
                "VALUES (?,?,?)";
            var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
            stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
            stmt.text = sql;
            stmt.parameters[0] = note.title;
            stmt.parameters[1] = note.time;
            stmt.parameters[2] = note.message;
            stmt.execute();
        }

        public static function addMember(note:Member):void
        {
            var sql:String = 
                "INSERT INTO notes (FirstName, FamilyName, Age, Sex, Notes) " +
                "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
            var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
            stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
            stmt.text = sql;
            stmt.parameters[0] = note.FirstName;
            stmt.parameters[1] = note.FamilyName;
            stmt.parameters[2] = note.Age;
            stmt.parameters[3] = note.Sex;
            stmt.parameters[4] = note.Notes;
            stmt.execute();
        }

        public static function deleteNote(note:Dish):void
        {
            var sql:String = "DELETE FROM notes WHERE id=?";
            var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
            stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
            stmt.text = sql;
            stmt.parameters[0] = note.id;
            stmt.execute();
        }

        public static function deleteMember(note:Dish):void
        {
            var sql:String = "DELETE FROM notes WHERE id=?";
            var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
            stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
            stmt.text = sql;
            stmt.parameters[0] = note.id;
            stmt.execute();
        }

        public static function updateNote(note:Dish):void
        {
            var sql:String = "UPDATE notes SET title=?, time=?, message=? WHERE id=?";
            var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
            stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
            stmt.text = sql;
            stmt.parameters[0] = note.title;
            stmt.parameters[1] = note.time;
            stmt.parameters[2] = note.message;
            stmt.parameters[3] = note.id;
            stmt.execute();
        }

        public static function updateMember(note:Member):void
        {
            var sql:String = "UPDATE Members SET FirstName=?, FamilyName=?, Sex=?, Age=?, Notes=? WHERE ID=?";
            var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
            stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
            stmt.text = sql;
            stmt.parameters[0] = note.FirstName;
            stmt.parameters[1] = note.FamilyName;
            stmt.parameters[2] = note.Sex;
            stmt.parameters[3] = note.Age;
            stmt.parameters[4] = note.Notes;            
            stmt.execute();
        }


        protected static function processRow(o:Object):Dish
        {
            var note:Dish = new Dish();
            note.id = o.id;
            note.title = o.title == null ? "" : o.title;
            note.time = o.time == null ? "" :o.time;
            note.message = o.message == null ? "" : o.message;
            return note;
        }

        protected static function processRow2(o:Object):Member
        {
            var info:Member = new Member();
            info.ID = o.ID;
            info.FirstName = o.FirstName == null ? "" : o.FirstName;
            info.FamilyName = o.FamilyName == null ? "" : o.FamilyName;
            info.Sex = o.Sex == null ? "" : o.Sex;
            info.Age = o.Age == null ? "" : o.Age;
            info.Notes = o.Notes == null ? "" : o.Notes;

            return info;
        }


        public static function openDatabase(file:File):void
        {
            var newDB:Boolean = true;
            if (file.exists)
                newDB = false;
            _sqlConnection = new SQLConnection();
            _sqlConnection.open(file);
            if (newDB)
            {
                createDatabase();
                populateDatabase();
            }
        }

        protected static function createDatabase():void
        {
            var sql:String = 
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS notes ( "+
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "title VARCHAR(50), " +
                "time VARCHAR(50), " +
                "message VARCHAR(200))"
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS members ( "+
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "title VARCHAR(50), " +
                "time VARCHAR(50), " +
                "message VARCHAR(200))"
                ;
            var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
            stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
            stmt.text = sql;
            stmt.execute();         
        }

        protected static function populateDatabase():void
        {
            var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("assets/notes.xml");
            if (!file.exists) return;
            var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
            stream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
            var xml:XML = XML(stream.readUTFBytes(stream.bytesAvailable));
            stream.close();
            for each (var n:XML in xml.note)
            {
                var note:Dish = new Dish();
                note.id = n.id;
                note.title = n.title;
                note.time = n.time;
                note.message = n.message;
                addNote(note);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and 
member.as

```
    package model
{
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
    import mx.core.IUID;

    [Bindable]
    public class Member implements IUID
    {
        public var ID:int;
        public var FirstName:String;
        public var FamilyName:String;
        public var Sex:String;
        public var AgeID:int;
        public var Notes:String;
        public var Fname:String;
        public var Famname:String;
        public var Age:String;




        public function get uid(): String {
            return ID.toString();
        }

        public function set uid(value: String): void {
            ID = parseInt(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL command is:

```
UPDATE Members SET FirstName=?, FamilyName=?, Sex=?, Age=?, Notes=? WHERE ID=?
```

But you are setting only the parameters for the five fields to be updated:

```java
stmt.parameters[0] = note.FirstName;
stmt.parameters[1] = note.FamilyName;
stmt.parameters[2] = note.Sex;
stmt.parameters[3] = note.Age;
stmt.parameters[4] = note.Notes;
```

You also have to set the `ID` value.